# Line-height bug on comment?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Here comes a snapshot of a small css line-height bug due to background color on username in comment :

[image: css bug]

I'm running FF4 under ubuntu 10.04

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that appears to have been resolved some time ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be a problem anymore.  I suspect it got fixed with a commenting refactor I did last year.